# To have selected dropdown menu according to value from database in edit form using haml and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the code for a dropdown menu in a form using haml

```
= f.select :people, options_for_select(['Kid','Youth','Man','woman'])
```

After form submit the value is stored in db. Now in Edit form I want this dropdown menu with the value selected according to stored value in database. How to do it using haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= f.select :people, options_for_select([your options here], selected: @variable.people)
```

where @variable is the name of the object you're getting the option for.